# Aligning the Legend Values in Charts

Tags: qlikview

How can I center the legend values in QlikView? I know how to move the legend to the bottom of the chart and to order the legend values horizontally. However how I want the the values are alligned in the center and not to the left.

Comment: I don't think that is possible in the standard QlikView charts

Answer (score 1):

If you hold down CTRL+SHIFT after clicking on the chart, you can drag the chart elements around, including the legend.  If you drag the legend all the way to the bottom of the chart, for example, it will snap to the bottom of the chart and create a 'low profile' legend centred across the bottom of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

The legend on the right is the only option. You can align it vertically, Go to Chart Properties -> Presentation -> Legend Settings -> Vertical Alignment.